# Masterless puppet with hiera

Tags: puppet, environment, hiera

I'm trying to figure out masterless environment with puppet. I'm using [this link](http://stdout.no/puppet-on-raspberry-pi/) to install the newest version of Puppet on Ubuntu.

I'm using this repository https://github.com/szymonrychu/puppet-masterless and running the script: **modules/os/files/puppet.sh**.

It downloads current Puppet repository to the `/opt/puppet` directory and then runs the code specified in it. (It sets cronjob pointing to the script, so it will run every hour)

After first run the hiera env is prepared (hiera.yaml) and deployed. From that point the code should start connect to hiera database, but it's not happening.

Most probably there is an issue in **modules/os/files/hiera.yaml** or in **manifests/site.pp**, but after several days of struggling I can't get it to work.

Comment: What, exactly, is not working?

Comment: In puppet code, in os module, I have several variables. I want to overwrite them with hiera. For example there is 'version' variable. By default it is equal to 'v0.0.0'. I want to have the hiera configured in way that this variable would be overwritten to 'ugabuga' everytime puppet executes the configuration,  but I'm missing something..

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I know what was broken :) 
first missing part in **common.yaml**:

```
(...)
classes:
 - os
os::version: 'ugabuga'
(...)
```

second mistake in **modules/os/manifests/init.pp**:

```
class os (
  $version = 'v0.0.0'
){ (...) }
```

instead of:

```
class os {
$version = 'v0.0.0'
(...)
}
```

and finally, the code should be included in **manifests/site.pp** like this:

```
node default {
  hiera_include('classes')
  include os
}
```

And that's it! But it wasn't trivial - at least for me. Documentation isn't that specific in that case and there are no complex examples about this.